# How to pull a related 'anchor' value on all recursive rows of a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using the following website as a starting point (https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) ,
I have made a CTE query that looks like:

```
    WITH q (n, Part_Number, Job, Material) AS (
SELECT
    0,
    Material.Part_Number,
    Material_Req.Job,
    Material_Req.Material
FROM 
    Production.dbo.Material_Req
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTION.dbo.Material ON Material_Req.Job = Material.Job
WHERE e.Job LIKE 'TEMPLATE%' AND e.Material IN  ('PART1')
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    n + 1,
    Material.Part_Number,
    Material_Req.Job,
    Material_Req.Material
FROM 
    Production.dbo.Material_Req
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTION.dbo.Material ON Material_Req.Job = Material.Job
    INNER JOIN q ON q.Material = Material.Material
    WHERE Material.Job LIKE 'TEMPLATE%')
SELECT DISTINCT n, Job, Part_Number, Material FROM q WHERE Job LIKE 'TEMPLATE%'
ORDER BY n
```

which produces results that would look like the table below, which is relatively navigable, especially if the end-user knows the content.

| n | Job | Part_Number | Material |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | TEMP1 | PART1 | PART1a |
| 0 | TEMP1 | PART1 | PART1b |
| 1 | TEMP2 | PART1a | MATERIAL1 |
| 1 | TEMP3 | PART1b | PART1b1 |
| 2 | TEMP4 | PART1b1 | PART1b1a |
| 3 | TEMP5 | PART1b1a | MATERIAL2 |

However, if I were to include multiple PART's in the WHERE condition on the anchor, e.g.

```
WHERE e.Job LIKE 'TEMPLATE%' AND e.Material IN  ('PART1', 'PART2', ..., 'PART99')
```

The resulting table would be exponentially harder to navigate.

I would like to be able to somehow append the original anchor 'PART' that the recursive row originated from. Is this even possible? I cannot comprehend how. The resulting table would look something like:

| n | Job | Part_Number | Material | Anchor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | TEMP1 | PART1 | PART1a | PART1 |
| 0 | TEMP1 | PART1 | PART1b | PART1 |
| 0 | TEMP8 | PART2 | PART2a | PART2 |
| 1 | TEMP2 | PART1a | MATERIAL1 | PART1 |
| 1 | TEMP3 | PART1b | PART1b1 | PART1 |
| 1 | TEMP9 | PART2a | PART2a1 | PART2 |
| 2 | TEMP4 | PART1b1 | PART1b1a | PART1 |
| 2 | TEMP10 | PART2a1 | MATERIAL7 | PART2 |
| 3 | TEMP5 | PART1b1a | MATERIAL2 | PART1 |

Comment: You may use any column available in the involved tables. So you need to add additional column to the `with q (..., Material) as (...`, define it as `Material` is anchor `select`, then pull it again from `q`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I am understand correctly, you just need to expose the `Part_Number` column twice in then "upper" `SELECT` and then put the CTE's column in the "lower" one:

```sql
WITH q AS
    (SELECT 0 AS n,
            Material.Part_Number,
            Material_Req.Job,
            Material_Req.Material,
            Material.Part_Number AS Anchor
     FROM Production.dbo.Material_Req
          INNER JOIN PRODUCTION.dbo.Material ON Material_Req.Job = Material.Job
     WHERE e.Job LIKE 'TEMPLATE%'
       AND e.Material IN ('PART1')
     UNION ALL
     SELECT n + 1,
            Material.Part_Number,
            Material_Req.Job,
            Material_Req.Material,
            q.Anchor
     FROM Production.dbo.Material_Req
          INNER JOIN PRODUCTION.dbo.Material ON Material_Req.Job = Material.Job
          INNER JOIN q ON q.Material = Material.Material
     WHERE Material.Job LIKE 'TEMPLATE%')
SELECT DISTINCT
       n,
       Job,
       Part_Number,
       Material,
       anchor
FROM q
WHERE Job LIKE 'TEMPLATE%'
ORDER BY n;
```

Comment: `q   (n, Part_Number, Job, Material)`, so it should not have `anchor` column. Or am I missing something T-SQL specific?

Comment: It should, I rarely (never) define the columns in my `WITH` clause so i missed adding it, @astentx . I've, instead, given the first column an alias and dropped the aliasing in the `WITH`

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much. CTE's and recursion in SQL are both new to me so I am still trying to comprehend how to do different things. Too quick for me to approve as the answer yet lol